# nodejs express приложение имеет большое время ответа

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Измеряю время работы вот такого кода:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ test: "test" })
})
```

Измерял с помощью console.time('label') и console.timeEnd('label'). Так же использовал npm модуль response-time, он пишет время генерации в хедер ответа. "Показания" console.time и response-time примерно совпадают: 15-30 миллисекунд. Но если открывать приложение в броузере, либо дергать его curl'ом то время ответа увеличивается примерно на 50мс. Грубо говоря, результат одной строки кода

```
res.send({ test: "test" })
```

броузер и curl ждут 60-70мс. Причем если в код добавить запрос в монгу и возврат результатов в ответ, то время фактически не изменяется, остается таким же.

Это не сходится с "десятками тысяч ответов в секунду", как говорят про nodejs. Почему ответ на запрос формируется так долго?

Comment: Десятки тысяч ответом в секунду имееться ввиду асинхронных.

Comment: а с чем именно вы сравниваете? что является у вас эталоном?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, с чем тут сравнивать. Например nginx отдает мелкую статику за 2мс. Golang app аналогичную задачу решает тоже за 2-5мс. Но вопрос больше не в этом. Вопрос в том, откуда берутся лишние 50 мс в работе nodejs? Чтоб понять что это за 50мс нужно перечитать мой вопрос.